# How to solve npm install babel-core but still not installed?

Tags: npm, vuejs2

I did try `sudo su` at beginning. Then `sudo npm install babel-core` and `npm install babel-core`

This is the error even if how many times I installed the babel-core.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

Use `sudo` if needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not working. the babel-core is in the node_modules folder but still its not detecting it. I used `sudo` as well

Comment: Try removing the node modules folder and then installing all the packages along with the new one

Comment: Okay. I deleted the node_modules folder and installing everything with `sudo`. seems working. Im still wondering why `sudo su` is not working.

Comment: Ok, post a question to remove Sudo I will answer that too, or else search about it you will get answer.

Comment: I'll do some research about it. I'll let you know if I can't solved it.